# sort php multidimensional array by specified set of values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in this structure:

```
$arr = Array 
   ( 
        [0] => Array 
            ( 
                [ref] => Q1 
            ) 
        [1] => Array 
            ( 
                [ref] => C6 
            ) 
        [2] => Array 
            ( 
                [ref] => C13 
            ) 
        [3] => Array 
            ( 
                [ref] => S3 
            ) 
        [4] => Array 
            ( 
                [ref] => Q11 
            ) 
        [8] => Array 
            ( 
                [ref] => S7 
            ) 
        [9] => Array 
            ( 
                [ref] => C4 
            ) 
   );
```

I want to sort the array so that the order of values are S, Q, D, C, P, E and if possible have each alphanumeric ascending while also keeping the associate key [ref], like this:

```
Array 
   ( 
        [0] => Array 
            ( 
                [ref] => S3
            ) 
        [1] => Array 
            ( 
                [ref] => S7
            ) 
        [2] => Array 
            ( 
                [ref] => Q1
            ) 
        [3] => Array 
            ( 
                [ref] => Q11   
            ) 
        [4] => Array 
            ( 
                [ref] => C4  
            ) 
        [8] => Array 
            ( 
                [ref] => C6
            ) 
        [9] => Array 
            ( 
                [ref] => C13
            ) 
   )
```

I've looked into the php functions available such as <strike>usort and uasort but these do not seem to deal with alphanumeric values</strike>.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you missing keys 5, 6 and 7 on purpose, or was that a mistake?

Comment: I'm missing them on purpose.

Comment: `usort` and `uasort` both accept a *user*-defined comparison function, so they deal with whatever you tell them to deal with.

Comment: @iainn I'll change my incorrect statement, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do what you want. It uses `usort` with a compare function that first looks at the leading character and sorts that based on your specified order: S, Q, D, C, P, E. If the character is the same, it then compares the integer part of the value. Now the problem is that this loses the keys. We can't use [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) to get around that, as it will move the keys with the corresponding value. To get around that we first grab the keys of the array, then combine the keys with the sorted array at the end:

```
function mysort($a, $b) {
    $sort_order = ['S', 'Q', 'D', 'C', 'P', 'E'];
    // first, sort by leading character
    $s = array_search($a['ref'][0], $sort_order) - array_search($b['ref'][0], $sort_order);
    if ($s != 0) return $s;
    // if the same, sort by numeric part
    return (int)substr($a['ref'], 1) - (int)substr($b['ref'], 1);
}
$keys = array_keys($arr);
usort($arr, 'mysort');
$arr = array_combine($keys, $arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ref] => S3
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ref] => S7
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ref] => Q1
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [ref] => Q11
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [ref] => C4
        )
    [8] => Array
        (
            [ref] => C6
        )
    [9] => Array
        (
            [ref] => C13
        )
)
```

Comment: Much better answer than mine. I'm just going to delete it.

Comment: @Mike I think they were pretty similar. But thank you.

Comment: Mine didn't use natural sorting like yours did, so it (probably) gives a wrong answer, unless that's how the OP wants it. And using `array_combine` is much better than creating an array of keys and looping over it, and creating a duplicate array. I actually wasn't aware of that function.

Comment: Thank you very much Nick! Works perfectly.